# Can't compile Three20 template on iOS4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, three20, xcode-template

I pulled the latest version of three20 from github and installed their template. I opened it up in XCode, built it, ran it, then I realized the template isn't iOS4 ready.

The first issue I found was "Base SDK not found". I solved it in Edit Project Setting by  changing the Base SDK to "iOS Device 4.1".

Then I ran it again. I got tons of errors related to "Three20/Three.h: No such file or directory". I added the "../three20/src" to my Header Search Paths but it doesn't help.

Does anyone know why? What else should I change?

FYI:
XCode Version 3.2.4
Latest version of three20 (29 September)

Directories:
xcode/myproject/ 
xcode/three20/

PS: the template works fine in SDK 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out I have to use http://github.com/ECP/three20 instead .

Comment: There are hundreds of branches of facebook/Three20. This one u choosed seems to be quite outdated, as it was last touched july 6th, while facebook/Three20 has it last commit on august 20th

Comment: And this one is meant to be "project settings to work on ios4 + 3.1.3 as an example"

Actually if you are using the latest XCode, you still need to reset the base sdk. But this is all you have to do.

It works.

Answer (score 2):

I was pulling my hair out as well since adding three20 correctly to your new iOS4 with really basic instructions listed here: http://github.com/facebook/three20 did not work as well.

Issue: Can compile newly three20 to your iOS project and got this error: Can't find #import "Three20/Three20.h".

Here is the best solution for those have the same issue: 
1) Add your three20 to your iphone project path like this:  
     [yourProjectPath]/[iOSProjectName]/three20/.. 
2) cd three20 dir 
3) run: 
python src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p [yourProjectPath]/[iOSProjectName]/[iOSProjectName].xcodeproj Three20 -c Debug -c Release  
4) go to XCode and do a build now.

Thanks to jverkoey for adding this in ...man  
u save us a lot of headache if u ever read this :- ) kudos bud! :- )  
http://github.com/facebook/three20/commit/0814b1c149cbe987557c88a271f999c3f9f3ae64 
 
Please vote this answers if it help u. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

An answer I got from twitter - "need to manually set build target of each projects"
He might be right.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add the following to the Header Search Path in Xcode:

> three20/Build/Products/three20

Xcode 4 screen shot:

[image: Xcode header search path]

Yours may be different of course, but maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Also, try checking the Deployment Target under Project Settings, for both, Simulator and Device. In my case, I got thousands of errors because the target was set to 2.2. It seems there is no support for 2.2 anymore in iOS 4.1 and Xcode 3.2.4.